# How can I prevent my plants from getting eaten too fast?

Tags: aquarium, fish, eating, containment, aquatic-plants

I've got a huge problem with my fish and plants.  They eat them too rapidly. Put in 5 plants yesterday afternoon.  Today they are half eaten already.

Mostly, the sword bearers are responsible.

Eaters are 5 black mollies and 4 sword bearers.

Now, the question is: what can I do so that the plants survive a bit longer than 1-3 days?

[Picture of the aquarium](https://imgur.com/a/Ls8ZIdp?s=wa).

Comment: I doubt if those fish are eating Amazon sword or anubia. I have found Amazon swords to be  difficult to grow and fade like yours.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I only had anubia in the past but got a problem with the excretions of the fish and bacteria as the anubia didnt use that up e nough (aka N3 problem) thus need medium to fast growing plants in there too. But even with 5 plants in one go its 2 weeks top before they are eaten (even if every 3 days they get a leaf of salad,...